# Android leanback library ListRowPresenter whole row expand

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

I'm trying to make the whole row expand when selected in leanback library carousel.

Effect that I want : [image: Effect that I want]

I'm working off the android TV sample code.
I have tried `setExpandedRowHeight(..);` and `setRowHeight(..);`

```
/**
 * Created by sylversphere on 15-03-16.
 */
public class ExperimentalFragment extends BrowseFragment{

    private ArrayObjectAdapter mRowsAdapter;
    private ExperimentalCardPresenter mCardPresenter;
    private int NUM_ROWS = 20;
    private int NUM_COLS = 40;
    private Context context;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        context = getActivity();
        setTitle("Hello there you kid"); // Badge, when set, takes precedent
        setHeadersState(HEADERS_DISABLED);
        loadRows();
    }

    private void loadRows() {
        List<Movie> list = MovieList.setupMovies();

        final ListRowPresenter lrp = new ListRowPresenter(FocusHighlight.ZOOM_FACTOR_LARGE);
        lrp.setRowHeight(100);
        lrp.setExpandedRowHeight(200);

        mRowsAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(lrp);

        mCardPresenter = new ExperimentalCardPresenter();

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++) {
            ArrayObjectAdapter listRowAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(mCardPresenter);
            for (int j = 0; j < NUM_COLS; j++) {
                listRowAdapter.add(list.get(j % 5));
            }
            mRowsAdapter.add(new ListRow(listRowAdapter));
        }

        setAdapter(mRowsAdapter);
    }

    private void say(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Say : "+s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

but the rows stay the same. I tried animating rows manually but rows now don't have proper padding between them.
How would I make rows expand and keep the padding?

Answer (score 1):

By using setExpandedRowHeight you're just setting the height, but not really expanding the row. You need to explicitly set row view expanded when you want it to be expanded by calling [setRowViewExpanded](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/RowPresenter.html#setRowViewExpanded%28android.support.v17.leanback.widget.Presenter.ViewHolder,%20boolean%29) method

```
public final void setRowViewExpanded (Presenter.ViewHolder holder, boolean expanded)
```

Comment: This doesn't expand when row is selected. Rather, it expands row when the gridview (Child of the menu item) is selected.